# collect metrics from different pods in prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, containers, prometheus

i want to collect metrics from a deployment (with multiple pods) from Kubernetes, and on of my metrics is the number of calls that my deployment received, my question is about Prometheus, how can i tell Prometheus to call all the pods that are part of the deployment and collect metrics from them? And what is the best practice to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend using [prometheus-operator](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator) to do all heavy lifting with configuring Prometheus monitoring for your applications.

For example, having the Deployment and Service like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example-app
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: example-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: example-app
        image: fabxc/instrumented_app
        ports:
        - name: web
          containerPort: 8080
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: example-app
  labels:
    app: example-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: example-app
  ports:
  - name: web
    port: 8080
```

You may configure `ServiceMonitor` object which will use Service as a service discovery endpoint to find all the pods of the Deployment. This assumes that your application is exposing metrics using HTTP path `/metrics`.

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: example-app
  labels:
    team: frontend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example-app
  endpoints:
  - port: web
```

This will make Prometheus scrape metrics for your application.

You may read more about ServiceMonitors here: https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/user-guides/getting-started.md